# Python Regex Raw: how to match new lines for each line in consecutive lines?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
s = """
{
    "list-of-stuff": "{
        (analog-input, 1), (analog-input, 2), (analog-input, 3),
        (analog-input, 4), (analog-input, 5), (analog-input, 6),
        (analog-input, 7), (analog-input, 8), (analog-input, 9),
        (analog-input, 10), (analog-input, 11), (analog-input, 12),
        (analog-input, 13), (analog-input, 14), (analog-input, 15),
        (analog-input, 16), (analog-input, 17), (analog-input, 18),
        (analog-input, 19), (analog-input, 20), (analog-input, 21),
        (analog-input, 22), (analog-input, 23), (analog-input, 24),
        (analog-input, 25), (analog-input, 26), (analog-input, 27),
        (analog-input, 28), (analog-input, 29), (analog-input, 30),
        (analog-input, 31), (analog-input, 32), (analog-output, 1)
    }"
},
{
    "identifier": "(analog-input, 0)",
    "name": "AI 00",
    "type": "analog-input",
    "value": "?",
    "description": "Temp",
    "flags": "{false,false,false}",
    "state": "normal",
    "service": "FALSE",
    "reliability": "?"
}
"""
```

And I want to convert all newline characters in the second string (`{...}`) from `\n` to `\\n`. (I am trying to make this JSON readable) How can I do this?

Here are my attempts:

```
s = re.sub(r'^[^"}]+,(\s*)\n', r'\1,\2\\n', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
s = re.sub(r'^[^"}]+,(\s*)$', r'\1,\2\\n', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Unfortunately, neither works. The closest I get produces the following output:

```
s = """
{
    "list-of-stuff": "{
        (analog-input, 1), (analog-input, 2), (analog-input, 3),
        (analog-input, 4), (analog-input, 5), (analog-input, 6),
        (analog-input, 7), (analog-input, 8), (analog-input, 9),
        (analog-input, 10), (analog-input, 11), (analog-input, 12),
        (analog-input, 13), (analog-input, 14), (analog-input, 15),
        (analog-input, 16), (analog-input, 17), (analog-input, 18),
        (analog-input, 19), (analog-input, 20), (analog-input, 21),
        (analog-input, 22), (analog-input, 23), (analog-input, 24),
        (analog-input, 25), (analog-input, 26), (analog-input, 27),
        (analog-input, 28), (analog-input, 29), (analog-input, 30),\n        (analog-input, 31), (analog-input, 32), (analog-output, 1)
    }"
},
{
    "identifier": "(analog-input, 0)",
    "name": "AI 00",
    "type": "analog-input",
    "value": "?",
    "description": "Temp",
    "flags": "{false,false,false}",
    "state": "normal",
    "service": "FALSE",
    "reliability": "?"
}
"""
```

It seems that `re.MULTILINE` mode makes one match on all consecutive lines. However, I need to match EACH line. Unfortunately I need `re.MULTILINE` or else the `\n`'s do not get matched. Any suggestions?

**Update**

I updated my question to better reflect my situation. The string has other properties that I needed to meet, which is shown in my regex. For example, I need to exclude `},` from my matches, as well as other lines that are not inside a JSON string. Thus, I cannot simply replace all `\n` with `\\n`.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MULTILINE thing isn't the right way to tackle this; there's a much simpler issue with a much simpler solution.

In regular expressions, repetition is greedy by default. So `[^"}]+` will match as many characters as it can while still making the rest of the pattern match. The *last* `\n` in the input ends up matching the `\n` in your pattern, with the intervening `\n`s matching as part of the `[^"}]+`.

But you can make it non-greedy just by using `+?` instead of `+`, in which case it will match as *few* characters as it can while still making the rest of the pattern match. So the *first* `\n` in the input ends up matching the one in your pattern, so each line is a separate match.

```
^[^"}]+?,(\s*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TEfCTSJHPtpfpfeK)

Comment: +1 `The MULTILINE thing isn't the right way to tackle this` and `regex`

Answer (score 3):

ErlVolton Solution fit the best what you wan to do. But if you still want to use string manipulations or regexes to do this. You can simply do :

```
s = s.replace('\n','\\n')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's trying to replace the `\n`s only on lines that don't end a JSON object or string, hence the `[^"}]` part. This will replace them on _all_ lines, including the ones he doesn't want. Which is closer than replacing them on only one line (the last one before the end of the object), but still not right.

Comment: @abarnert didn't seen that indeed. Then in that case the non-greedy approach you provide is the best way along with the KISS json.dumps.

Comment: @abarnert has the correct insight. My question has been updated to include more information about my situation. I should have made this more clear in my original question.

Comment: @Lucas then I recommend you abarnert answer. Note that the non-greedy approach is usefull in a lot of cases where you have to match "everything until a precise caracter"

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately no regex-fu is needed to escape something so it is valid JSON.  The [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) will do it for you, specifically [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps).  I'm not going to use your example text because it's not valid python, you have a multiline string with no triple quotes and no continuation.

```
>>> import json
>>> x = "foo\nbar"
>>> json.dumps(x)
'"foo\\nbar"'
```

To answer your literal question, I think `re.sub("\n","\\\\n", your_text)` would work fine:

```
>>> import re
>>> y = "foo\nbar\njaz"
>>> re.sub("\n","\\\\n",y)
'foo\\nbar\\njaz'
```

Comment: `json.dumps` isn't going to turn a not-quite-valid JSON string into a valid JSON string. Well, it _is_, but it'll be a valid JSON string representation of his original string, not of what his string was supposed to represent, and I don't see how that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use multi-line string like this:

```
s= '''
"list-of-stuff": "{ 
(analog-input, 1), (analog-input, 2), (analog-input, 3), 
(analog-input, 4), (analog-input, 5), (analog-input, 6), 
(analog-input, 7), (analog-input, 8), (analog-input, 9), 
(analog-input, 10), (analog-input, 11), (analog-input, 12), 
(analog-input, 13), (analog-input, 14), (analog-input, 15), 
(analog-input, 16), (analog-input, 17), (analog-input, 18), 
(analog-input, 19), (analog-input, 20), (analog-input, 21), 
(analog-input, 22), (analog-input, 23), (analog-input, 24), 
(analog-input, 25), (analog-input, 26), (analog-input, 27), 
(analog-input, 28), (analog-input, 29), (analog-input, 30), 
(analog-input, 31), (analog-input, 32), (analog-output, 1)
}"'''

s.replace('\n','\\n')
```

Now replace will work